# Can you use a list of enum values in Kotlins when?

Tags: kotlin, enums, switch-statement

I was wondering if it is possible to use a list in a `when` statement in order to make it exhaustive. Let's assume we have the following enum:

```
enum class SomeType {
    TYPE_ONE,
    TYPE_TWO,
    TYPE_THREE;

    companion object {
        fun groupThese() = listOf(TYPE_TWO, TYPE_THREE)
    }
}
```

If we now want to make an exhaustive when statement for this enum, can we use the list `groupThese()` somehow?

```
when (type) {
    TYPE_ONE -> doSomething()
    SomeType.groupThese() -> doSomethingElse() //this does obviously not work
}
```

I know I could write the enum values down explicitly inside the `when`, but I would like to keep the list in one place so I only need to change it once if I have to change it in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `groupThese()` returns a `list` so you can use the operator `in`:

```
when (type) {
    SomeType.TYPE_ONE -> doSomething()
    in SomeType.groupThese() -> doSomethingElse()
    else -> doSomethingDifferent()
}
```

Documentation: [When Expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression)

In this case `else` would also work:

```
when (type) {
    SomeType.TYPE_ONE -> doSomething()
    else -> doSomethingElse()
}
```

Comment: This does not make it exhaustive. Getting the error `'when' expression must be exhaustive, add necessary 'TYPE_TWO', 'TYPE_THREE' branches or 'else' branch instead`

Comment: For the sample that you posted you only need else. If there are other values in the enum also then add an else part. I edited.